# Sending POST and going to the page with PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with POST and I hope someone can help me. I have two pages, A and B. I need to send some data through POST from A to B, and B can't be modified in any way. How can I send my POST data from A to B, using PHP? The thing is: I don't need to just send the data, I need to go to the page as well, while sending the post, since B creates a cookie that I need.

header + curl? fsockopen? curl only?

Comment: Not possibe with PHP if it goes across domains.

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure what you are asking, or if i am simplifying it but check out this:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

If all you need to do is send data from page A to page B and then navigate to page B, then set the action of the form to page b, so when you hit the button, you will navigate there.

Comment: Please do not use or cite w3schools.  See [this page](http://www.w3fools.com) for reasons and details.

Answer (score 0):

If something is just too complicated, maybe you're going on the wrong way.

Why do you need such a thing? Can't you just redirect to that page using a form with action="post"? This is the most used way to do what you want, almost every site use this.

If not, tell us the real problem, what you said is a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a form and set the action to equal B and the method to 'POST', and then have the data you want to send in input tags and don't forget to give each input tag a name and then add a submit button.

When one clicks on the submit button it will send the data to page B and transfer you to that page

Comment: I need to send that info in the background, i can't have a form. I tried using cURL along with header, but didn't work well, since cURL sent the post data, and header sent to the page. Two different connections.

Comment: In short terms, i have to redirect the user to another page with POST data in this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little unclear .

In page A,  you need to set the form action for example  then you can get your values in page B and also you will navigated to page B

Comment: In page A i have an array that i want to pass as POST data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the cookies fro a different domain to be set to a client / visitor, you'll have to get them there, which essentially means *they* will have to do the post (doing it with curl from you own server still leaves you with no way to set the cookies). The only feasible solution I can see is to perform a post with client-sided scripting (i.e. javascript).

You *cannot* let the user do a POST with PHP. Period, no way whatsoever. Sure, you can post from your own server what you like,  but it won't do a lick of good as long as you cannot get the cookie information to the client, which you can't due to browser security / privacy issues.